# Model four levels deep -- Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

How do I set up the associations more than two levels deep? I have a resource User that has_one Blog which has many Posts which has many Comments which has_one Contact. Already User has_may Contacts. But what do I do with the rest? Should user have_many Posts :through => Blog? or should I have Post reference User directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the many possible direct and through associations, you have a lot of choices, and there aren't any strict rules. So set up what you need. You do have a lot of depth in associations, but do you really want user.posts since they'd be across different blogs? I added it anyway, below.

```
class User
  has_many :blogs
  has_many :contacts, :through => :user_contacts
  has_many :posts, :through => :blogs

class UserContacts
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :contact

class Blog
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :posts

class Post
  belongs_to :blog
  has_many :comments

class Comment
  belongs_to :post
  has_one :contact

class Contact
  has_many :comments
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I ended up modifying it slightly because each user has_one blog.